# API request(nodejs) return nothing, but $.getJSON() return the expected data

Tags: node.js, api, request

[Nodejs request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4DBM.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4DBM.png).The request is successful with statusCode =200 but there is no data in body parameter

[$.getJSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Mso.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Mso.png).This is the jquery getJSON request and the data is return as expectation 
Could you tell me what problems are happening ?

Comment: I assumed you use [NPM `request` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), and I didn't have any problem reproducing your call with a fresh install of this package, it works and retrieves the response properly... Anyway, please avoid screenshots of code (because we can't copy-paste to reproduce your issue), have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, you might want to provide a code that does _not_ contain your own private access tokens.

Comment: try to console response.json()